# Combine 2 commits that are NOT the last 2 commits on my branch

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-squash

I have to following 4 commits:

```
#Commit4
#Commit3
#Commit2
#Commit1
```

After making commits 3 and 4 I realized my first 2 commits really should be a single commit like so:

```
#Commit4
#Commit3
#Commit1_and_commit2
```

Is an interactive rebase recommended for this or is there a better approach? Steps to follow would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, interactive rebase. "squash" or "fixup"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interactive rebase is far and away the easiest approach (though in fact it does nothing you couldn't do in some more difficult, manual way). You will need to say

```
git rebase -i --root
```

if commit 1 really is the very first commit. If not, you need to say

```
git rebase -i parentOfCommit1
```

You will then be shown a pick list of your four commits:

```
pick
pick
pick
pick
```

You will change that to

```
pick
squash
pick
pick
```

and you'll be all set.

Comment: It's the first commit on my brach off of master. Master obviously would have a long commit history.

Comment: Worked great, thank you. I used "git rebase -i HEAD~4" to get the list of the last 4 commits.